# Apache can't load dbi module in mac os x

Tags: macos, osx-lion, apache-http-server, mysql, perl

I installed `dbd:mysql` via `cpan`. I have the following simple script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -U
use DBI;
$ds = 'DBI:mysql:project:localhost'; $user = 'root'; $password = '123456';
$db = DBI->connect($ds, $user, $password) or die("Connection error\n");
$res = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM root");
$res->execute();
while (my @row = $res->fetchrow_array()) { print $row[0]; }
$res->finish();
$db->disconnect();
```

When I run it from terminal then everything is fine. But when I refer to it in the browser an error occurs. Apache error log:

> [error] [client 127.0.0.1] install_driver(mysql) failed: Can't load '/Library/Perl/5.12/darwin-thread-multi-2level/auto/DBD/mysql/mysql.bundle' for module DBD::mysql: dlopen(/Library/Perl/5.12/darwin-thread-multi-2level/auto/DBD/mysql/mysql.bundle, 1): Library not loaded: libmysqlclient.18.dylib
>
> [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   Referenced from: /Library/Perl/5.12/darwin-thread-multi-2level/auto/DBD/mysql/mysql.bundle
>
> [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   Reason: image not found at /System/Library/Perl/5.12/darwin-thread-multi-2level/DynaLoader.pm line 204.

I installed `mod_perl` and following the instructions changed the `httpd.conf`:

> LoadModule perl_module libexec/apache2/mod_perl.so
>
> PerlModule Apache::DBI

But now does not start apache. Error log:

> [error] Can't load '/Library/Perl/5.12/darwin-thread-multi-2level/auto/DBD/mysql/mysql.bundle' for module DBD::mysql: dlopen(/Library/Perl/5.12/darwin-thread-multi-2level/auto/DBD/mysql/mysql.bundle, 1): Library not loaded: libmysqlclient.18.dylib\n  Referenced from: /Library/Perl/5.12/darwin-thread-multi-2level/auto/DBD/mysql/mysql.bundle\n  Reason: image not found at /System/Library/Perl/5.12/darwin-thread-multi-2level/DynaLoader.pm line 204.\n at (eval 6) line 2\nCompilation failed in require at (eval 6) line 2.\n
>
> [error] Can't load Perl module DBD::Mysql for server MacBook-Pro-Evgenij.local:0, exiting...

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a symlink in `/usr/lib/` to `/usr/local/mysql-5.5.23-osx10.6-x86_64/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib`, rebuilt `dbd:mysql` and everything was working.